# Getting all selected values from Grid Row

Tags: asp.net, listview, gridview, drop-down-menu, checkbox

I had a gridview (Having 10 rows). Each row contains only one column, which has 1 checkbox, 2 dropdowns, 1 radiobutton list.

Now I need to get the selected values into List based on checkbox selected. I mean, if I checked first checkbox, first value in IList should have the name of that checkbox and its selected values of dropdowns and radiobuttonlist.

how this can be achieved? Can anyone help me on this?

```
/* Properties to get selected values */
public string SelectedChekbox
    {
        get { return _selectedChekbox; }
        set { _selectedChekbox = value; }
    }

    public string Ddl1Value
    {
        get { return _ddl1Value; }
        set { _ddl1Value = value; }
    }

    public string Ddl2Value
    {
        get { return _ddl2Value; }
        set { _ddl2Value = value; }
    }


/* This is the property in which I need values*/
public string SelectedGridValues
    {
        get { return _selectedGridValues; }
        set { _selectedGridValues = value; }
    }

/* To get the selected values of grid into list*/
/*** This was incomplete code. Need help to improve this ***/
private IList<MyList> LoadList()
    {

      foreach (DataListItem dlItem in dlDataList.Items)
      {
         GridView grid = (GridView)dlItem.FindControl("gvGridList");
         if (grid != null)
         {
           foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in grid.Rows)
           {
             CheckBox chk = gridRow.FindControl("chkSelect") as CheckBox;
             RadioButton rdo = gridRow.FindControl("rdoSelect") as RadioButton;
             DropDownList ddl1Value = gridRow.FindControl("ddl1") as DropDownList;
             DropDownList ddl1Value = gridRow.FindControl("ddl2") as DropDownList;

               if (chk.Checked && chk.Text == Name)
               {
                            _selectedGraph = chk.Text;
                            _ddl1Value = ddl1.SelectedValue;
                            _ddl1Value = ddl2.SelectedValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Instead of adding your name at the bottom of each question, please simply edit your user profile to add your name, that way your name will always be present while the question text concentrates on solely the question

Answer (score 0):

gridview is rendered to an html table, so try to inspect with something like firebug the exact selector but it should be something like

```
var myrows = $(".myTableClass tr").has("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
```

that should return only html table rows that has checked checkboxes.

from here u can continue to something like

> var selecteds = [];
>
> myrows.find("select option:selected").each(function(){ 
>   selecteds.push($(this).text());   });

hope i got u right, if not then reply me here

EDIT:

answering ur comments, and i hope i get u right u want an each list item to hold say cbxName, ddlVal and radioVal so u can make a "class" like this

```
function myType(cbxName, ddlVal , radioVal ){
    this.cbxName= cbxName;
    this.ddlVal = ddlVal ;
    this.radioVal = radioVal ;
};

var x = new myType(2, 3, 4);
```

then u iterate the rows like this:

> myrows.each(function(index, element){
>
> ```
> var r = $(this);
> var cbxName = r.find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("name");
> //or whatever the name is
> var ddlVal = r.find("select").text();
> //i think that will get u the selected text, if not do it like above
> var radioVal = r.find("radio selector").attr("ur-att");
> selecteds.push(new myType(cbxName , ddlVal , radioVal ));
> ```
>
> });

Comment: Currently i placed properties for checkbox and 2 radiobuttons and radiobuttonlist. I tried and succeed in saving single values (only checkbox names) into a list. But i cant get how to save checkbox names including with its dropdowns and radiobuttonlist values into the list. <br/>

Comment: i need List[0] should hold all the values like checkbox name, ddl value and radiobutton list value of one row in gridview. each row control values should saved in each index of list LIST[i]

Comment: in case u didnt notice i added and "EDIT" for u :)